# Non nested bounds for conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose you know how to simulate $X,Y$ two independent random variables in $\mathbb R$ and you are interested in the following quantity : 
$$
I = \mathbb P \left( \mathbb E \left[ Y|X\right] >a \right),
$$
where $a>0$.

Do you know any reference treating non nested lower and upper bounds for this quantity $I$ ? 
Applying Markov inequality, we would get : 
$$
I\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X|]}{a}
$$
but I am looking at more refined inequalities or even equality with $\sup$ or $\inf$. 
Thanks.